# Play Framework and Server Side Events or Websocket for specific client

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka, akka-stream

I am using Play Framework 2.6 with Java to implement a server for a REST API. Some REST calls include uploading an image to the server. The server has to process the image and should inform the client when it is done. Some images may be analyzed for 10 minutes or more, so the client REST call cannot wait for the answer. I am thinking about informing the client that the image is ready via Server Side Events (SSE) or WebSockets (WS), I prefer SSE.

I know the Play Framework example at https://github.com/playframework/play-java-streaming-example , but it is too simple since it just sends an event every 100ms to the client.

I also know the example at https://github.com/playframework/play-java-chatroom-example which demonstrates a chatroom which only sends events when a client sends a message. But (for me) there is too much "black magic" going because just a bunch of lines connects all the clients. The problem here is, it is broadcasting the messages, there is no control which client receives which message.

What I am really looking for is:
Tracking my clients (for example in a HashMap) so I can find them by a session ID and if there is message for a specific client, I pick this client from my Map, sent a Server Side Event to inform it that the image is processed. The client can then make another REST call to get the result.

Are there any examples or source code snippets to achieve that?

Looking forward for any help!

Thank you,
schube

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but might be an interesting read: how linkedin scaled their instant messaging in a similar architecture: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/10/instant-messaging-at-linkedin--scaling-to-hundreds-of-thousands-